# Hangfire use of variables inside jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I know hangfire doesn't run in same context as ASP.NET and it has its own thread pool but I should use variables inside my background jobs. It's understandable because in fact, those jobs may not run on same server. This means if I execute `_locked = false;` (in `Checker()`), it will never get applied because it's running in another context. It's the same for `BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Start(bot));`, if it was a recurring job (cron job), those variables I'm using inside, would always be reset on every single cron job pop up.

How do I use variables in this situation?

```
private UpdateSubscription _subscription;

private StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();
private bool _locked = false;

public void RunStart(Bot bot)
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Start(bot));
}

public void Start(Bot bot)
{
    ApplyCredentialsOnClient();

    var lastKnownKline = _client.GetKlines(bot.CryptoPair.Symbol, bot.TimeInterval.Interval, limit: 2).Data.First();
    _subscription = _socketClient.SubscribeToKlineUpdates(bot.CryptoPair.Symbol, bot.TimeInterval.Interval, async data =>
    {
        if (data.Data.Final)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Final | Open time: {data.Data.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()}");
        }

        if (lastKnownKline.OpenTime != data.Data.OpenTime)
        {
            // Static
            _logger.LogError($"Static | Open time: {lastKnownKline.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()} | {lastKnownKline.Close}");
        }
        else if (lastKnownKline.OpenTime == data.Data.OpenTime && lastKnownKline.Close != data.Data.Close)
        {
            // Real time
            if (!_locked)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Real time | Open time: {data.Data.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()} | {data.Data.Close}");
                _locked = true;

                BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Checker(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Locked");
            }
        }

        lastKnownKline = data.Data.ToKline();
    }).Data;
}

public void Checker()
{
    _logger.LogWarning($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()}");

    _locked = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi I think the _loger functions are syn mode when your calling function Async

Comment: @LDS, the context falls on `_locked` and not `_logger`.

Comment: IF so pass a variable value to the function and checked in the checker function like time

Comment: @LDS, the idea is to change an outside variable inside the job. Not to check its value.

Comment: @nop, why not define `_lock` as static variable or use a fast database like Redis to change `_lock` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple solutions come to my mind, I will start from the simplest one.

**If you are running a Single instance then:**

**1-** Use a static variable:

```
public static bool _locked = false;
```

Or

**2-** Define the whole class as Singleton in `startup`, so each time Hangfire tries to activate the class, it reaches to the same instance.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //....

    services.AddSingleton<SomeClass>();

    //....
}
```

**And if you are running this task on multiple instances**

Then you should store this variable to a database like `Redis` and change its states using the database. So the same variable can be accessed from multiple jobs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Nice catch with the static method. I don't know how I missed to try that. Earlier, I was using Redis implementation and I confirm that it works fine because it's cache is similar to EF's repository.